# Files and Exceptions for python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 1
inPut = input("Please enter a file name: ")
infile = open(inPut, "r")

line = infile.readline()
print("/*", a ,"*/", line)
while line !="" :
    a = a + 1
    line = infile.readline()
    print("/*",a,"/*", line)

infile.close()
```

So i've been working on this code to print out lines of text out of another file. I simply did a file with 4 lines of text, and created a print statement before the listed line to indicate which line it is. How could i alter my code so that it doesn't print a 5th line indicator when there is no text?

This is how it is printed:

```
/* 1 */ Hello
/* 2 */ My name 
/* 3 */ is 
/* 4 */ John
/* 5 */
```

I would like it to be printed as:

```
/* 1 */ Hello
/* 2 */ My name 
/* 3 */ is 
/* 4 */ John
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for a, line in enumerate(infile, 1):
    print("/*", a, "*/", line)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that print `/* 0 */ Hello`?

Comment: The second argument to `enumerate()` is optional and it is the starting index which defaults to `0`, I use `1` here.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your problem is more suited to using a for loop than a while loop.  Something like this:

```
input_filename = input("Please enter a file name: ")
with open(input_filename) as infile:
    for (line_number, line) in enumerate(infile, 1):
        if line:
            print("/*",a,"/*", line)
```

Improvements to note:

- The file handle itself is an iterator, so you don't need to use `readlines` or similar method, you can iterate it directly.
- Use of the `with` statement to correctly open and close the file handle
- Use of `enumerate` to get the line numbers (replaces your counter variable)
- More descriptive variable names
- The conditional `if line` works on the fact that an empty string is false, non-empty string is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can break out of your loop after you read the input.

```
while True:
    a = a + 1
    line = infile.readline()
    if line == "":
        break
    print("/*",a,"/*", line)
```

Comment: could you explain to me how the break statement works? I haven't go to that terminology yet. Thanks!

Comment: It simply terminates the loop. Just gets out of it as soon as you get to 'break' for the first time and goes to whatever is after the loop.

Comment: @F.J's answer is better though in terms of the general approach you should take.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop, combined with the readlines() function of the open file-like object. Also, you should probably use enumerate to enumerate over the lines you've read, like this:

```
inPut = input("Please enter a file name: ")
infile = open(inPut, "r")

for index, line in enumerate(infile.readlines()):
    print("/*", index, "/*", line)

infile.close()
```

In this example, I changed the name of your variable "a" to the name "index".

Another tip would be to use the [with statement](http://oreilly.com/catalog/lpython/chapter/ch09.html) (new in Python 2.5) to automagically close the file handle when you're done with it:

```
inPut = input("Please enter a file name: ")
with open(inPut, "r") as infile:
    for index, line in enumerate(infile.readlines()):
        print("/*", index, "/*", line)
```

Comment: No need to call `.readlines()` at all; file objects are iterables.